# Python loop seems not to be iterating

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

The below code is not acting as expected for me.

```
class stateClass:
  state = 0

states = []
states.append(stateClass)
states.append(stateClass)

def populateStates(states):
  for s in states:
    if s.state == 0
      print 'populating'
      s.state = 1

populateStates(states)
```

the output is

```
states array length: 2
populating
```

this is failing the second time

```
for s in states:
  if s.state == 0
```

if conditional is failing the second time although it is a different index in the array and thus the s.state should have been initialized to 0. So I think the loop is not iterating properly.

Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Why the semicolons? This is python, not javascript. :-)

Comment: You are adding the *class*, not *instances* to the array. Do you really want this?

Comment: sorry im switching over, I do it without realising

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `;`'s - this isn't C and co. etc...

```
class stateClass: 
    state = 0
```

Here you're creating a `class level attribute` - ie, `state` is shared by all instances of `stateClass`.

You're appending to your list `stateClass` itself - ie, the definition of the class, not an actual instance of a class...

As soon as you change `state` in one of them, all instances of `stateClass` now have that changed value.

You most likely want to be creating instances:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.state = number

Hawaii = State(50)  
Kentucky = State(23) # (making state numbers up here...) 

my_states = []
my_states.append(Hawaii)
my_states.append(Kentucky)
```

To then show state, do something like:

```
print Hawaii.state
```

If you wanted a `property` so it avoids explicit setting from outside the class then:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._state = number
    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state
```

Comment: How do I access the elements of the state then after initialisation? Hawaii.number isnt working for me?

Answer (score 5):

Python is not Java. The loop is fine, the problem is the class.

`state` is a class variable, not an instance variable. It is shared by all instances of the class. And you're not actually instantiating the class at all.

Do this instead:

```
class stateClass(object):
  def __init__(self):  
    self.state = 0

states.append(stateClass())
```

And you don't need the semicolons.